# FIXT.1.1 5.0 SP2 Unable to Send/Recv with certain tags included

Tags: c#, .net-core, client-server, fix-protocol, quickfixn

i'm working on FIX, both client and server. The FIX messages seems fine when i send standard NewOrderSingle and I get an ExecutionReport.

However, when the server tries to send an ExecutionReport with the following tags, it either gets rejected/not sent, or was sent but client didnt properly receive it. Here are the troublesome tags.....

```
exReport.SetField(new ApplVerID(ApplVerID.FIX50SP2));       // Tag 1128
```

When client received this tag, it will send a REJECT to server with....
Tag specified out of required order

```
exReport.SetField(new MDEntryID(oid));                      // Tag 278
```

When client received this tag, it will send a REJECT to server with....
Tag not defined for this message type

```
exReport.SetField(new OrderBook(1));                        // Tag 30001
```

When client received this tag, it will send a REJECT to server with....
Invalid tag number
[Please note for this case I added a NEW tag and already defined in cs files]

**Under FieldTags.cs**

```
public const int OrderBook = 30001;
```

**Under Fields.cs**

```
public sealed class OrderBook : IntField
{
    public const int TAG = 30001;

    public OrderBook()
        : base(Tags.OrderBook) { }
    public OrderBook(int val)
        : base(Tags.OrderBook, val) { }
}
```

I have no idea how to make these tags work, please someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have not used QuickFixN, so what I say is based on my knowledge of the FIX protocol rather than the product you are using.

The fields within a FIX message have some minimal ordering requirements imposed on them. In particular, all the *header* fields should be appear before any *body* fields, and any *trailer* fields should appear last in a message. The `ApplVerID` field is defined as belonging in the *header*, so a `"Tag specified out of required order"` error suggests that the field had been intermingled with *body* fields rather than appear with other *header* fields.

I assume your FIX applications make use of a FIX data dictionary, which is an XML file that defines fields, and whether those fields appear in the *header* or *trailer*, or the *body* of specific messages. If you examine your FIX data dictionary, you should be able to confirm that `ApplVerID` belongs in the *header* fields. You will probably also be able to verify that the `"Tag not defined for this message type"` error for the `MDEntryID` field is because the FIX dictionary definition for the message does not contain that field.

The `"Invalid tag number"` error message arises because you should have defined the new field in the FIX data dictionaries used by both the server and client applications, rather than write a C# class for the new field. (I am assuming the FIX product provides a compiler that will generate C# classes from a FIX data dictionary.)